# click a button on html which launches a runnable JAR application? possiblE?

Tags: java, html, sql, jdbc

Originally I had an applet that contained SQL server/jdbc stuff and wanted to use that applet in html but I guess it's not good to use SQL in html? because i kept getting millions of errors/exceptions and realized my applet would only work if i commented out my SQL code.

but anyways, is there a way that I can have a button on an html page that when it is clicked it will run the runnable JAR application not the applet? without causing errors..

I'm not sure what a JAva Web Start is or what a JNLP is but if anyone could explain/help? the Oracle Website doesnt explain well enough like how do i create a JNLP?

I currently have a runnable JAR file that was exported from eclipse that opens & runs when I click the icon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that Java Web Start is what you want to use. You have your JAR file built already, so you should be good to go by following this [Deploying a Java Web Start Application tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/deploying.html)

This will walk you through signing the JAR file, creating JNLP file. This web site contains an example of a JNLP file, and also contains more documentation on the structure of the JNLP file [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/deploymentInDepth/jnlpFileSyntax.html)

You'll then create a few simple lines of JavaScript, to be triggered when the user clicks a button. Something like this, as mentioned in the tutorial:

```
deployJava.createWebStartLaunchButton(URL_TO_JNLP, '1.7.0');
```